# KML data manipulation using PHP

Tags: php, python

I have a big kml file I would just like to get certain parts of it.

```
<td>MUNICITY PSGC</td>

<td>153606000</td>

</tr>

<tr bgcolor="#D4E4F3">

<td>MUNICITY NAME</td>

<td>BUBONG</td>
<coordinates> 121.9116664538692,6.448888587819113,0 121.9119650206403,6.449515350125353,0 121.9119422292838,6.449720472334889,0 121.9122248421055,6.45000080602091,0 121.9122248421055,6.450554635986066,0 121.912635086524,6.450967159540255,0 121.9127809512066,6.451110745086737,0 121.9127809512066,6.4513887996373,0 121.9124983383845,6.451666854187351,0 121.9124983383845,6.451944908737914,0 121.9122248421055,6.452222963288534,0 121.9122248421055,6.45305484780431,0 121.9116664538692,6.453610956904925,0 121.9116664538692,6.454440562285072,0 121.9108345693535,6.455277005071878,0 121.9108345693535,6.455555059622498,0 121.9105519565314,6.455833114172549,0 121.9105519565314,6.456111168723112,0 121.9102784602525,6.45639150240919,0 121.9091571255082,6.45639150240919,0 121.9077759692987,6.455001229657285,0 121.9077759692987,6.454720895971263,0 121.9075001938841,6.454445120556159,0 121.9075001938841,6.453610956904925,0 121.9076301046167,6.452879354358174,0 121.9078283894188,6.452177380575449,0 121.9080266742212,6.451500477284355,0 121.9082249590239,6.450880552385172,0 121.9083320783998,6.450292535384961,0 121.9083639862988,6.449711355791806,0 121.9084323603685,6.44918715459022,0 121.9088904666361,6.448610533268493,0 121.909163962915,6.44833247871793,0 121.9097223511518,6.44833247871793,0 121.9099730560743,6.448090890338392,0 121.9116664538692,6.448888587819113,0</coordinates>
```

The end file should be (in an excel or csv file

```
Municity PSGC    Municity Name       Coordinates
  153606000      BUBONG              121.9116664538692,6.448888587819113,0 121.9119650206403,6.449515350125353,0 121.9119422292838,6.449720472334889,0 121.9122248421055,6.45000080602091,0 121.9122248421055,6.450554635986066,0 121.912635086524,6.450967159540255,0 121.9127809512066,6.451110745086737,0 121.9127809512066,6.4513887996373,0 121.9124983383845,6.451666854187351,0 121.9124983383845,6.451944908737914,0 121.9122248421055,6.452222963288534,0 121.9122248421055,6.45305484780431,0 121.9116664538692,6.453610956904925,0 121.9116664538692,6.454440562285072,0 121.9108345693535,6.455277005071878,0 121.9108345693535,6.455555059622498,0 121.9105519565314,6.455833114172549,0 121.9105519565314,6.456111168723112,0 121.9102784602525,6.45639150240919,0 121.9091571255082,6.45639150240919,0 121.9077759692987,6.455001229657285,0 121.9077759692987,6.454720895971263,0 121.9075001938841,6.454445120556159,0 121.9075001938841,6.453610956904925,0 121.9076301046167,6.452879354358174,0 121.9078283894188,6.452177380575449,0 121.9080266742212,6.451500477284355,0 121.9082249590239,6.450880552385172,0 121.9083320783998,6.450292535384961,0 121.9083639862988,6.449711355791806,0 121.9084323603685,6.44918715459022,0 121.9088904666361,6.448610533268493,0 121.909163962915,6.44833247871793,0 121.9097223511518,6.44833247871793,0 121.9099730560743,6.448090890338392,0 121.9116664538692,6.448888587819113,0
```

Does anyone know of a PHP or Python Script to get this.
Thanks again guys.

Comment: Please provide the code you've written so far, since [StackOverflow is not a code-writing platform](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You might want to take a look at [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) for parsing HTML source in Python. If this would be too much overhead, try developing a [regular expression](https://regex101.com/#python) for this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to export to excel without HTML tags and show the result this way , so try this one :

```
<?php
header( "Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=UTF-16LE" );  
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary"); 
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='".date("Y-m-d")."'.xls"); 
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Cache-Control: private",false);
?>
<table><tr><td>MUNICITY PSGC</td><td>MUNICITY NAME</td><td>coordinates</td></tr>
<tr align=center><td valign=top>153606000</td><td valign=top>BUBONG </td><td valign=top>121.9116664538692,6.448888587819113,0 121.9119650206403,6.449515350125353,0 121.9119422292838,6.449720472334889,0 121.9122248421055,6.45000080602091,0 121.9122248421055,6.450554635986066,0 121.912635086524,6.450967159540255,0 121.9127809512066,6.451110745086737,0 121.9127809512066,6.4513887996373,0 121.9124983383845,6.451666854187351,0 121.9124983383845,6.451944908737914,0 121.9122248421055,6.452222963288534,0 121.9122248421055,6.45305484780431,0 121.9116664538692,6.453610956904925,0 121.9116664538692,6.454440562285072,0 121.9108345693535,6.455277005071878,0 121.9108345693535,6.455555059622498,0 121.9105519565314,6.455833114172549,0 121.9105519565314,6.456111168723112,0 121.9102784602525,6.45639150240919,0 121.9091571255082,6.45639150240919,0 121.9077759692987,6.455001229657285,0 121.9077759692987,6.454720895971263,0 121.9075001938841,6.454445120556159,0 121.9075001938841,6.453610956904925,0 121.9076301046167,6.452879354358174,0 121.9078283894188,6.452177380575449,0 121.9080266742212,6.451500477284355,0 121.9082249590239,6.450880552385172,0 121.9083320783998,6.450292535384961,0 121.9083639862988,6.449711355791806,0 121.9084323603685,6.44918715459022,0 121.9088904666361,6.448610533268493,0 121.909163962915,6.44833247871793,0 121.9097223511518,6.44833247871793,0 121.9099730560743,6.448090890338392,0 121.9116664538692,6.448888587819113,0</td></tr><table>
```